How to find possibly corrupt album artwork in Music app?
Suddenly I have about 10,000 of 30,000 tracks not showing artwork on my iPhone’s Music app.
My MacBook’s Music app shows all tracks on all albums have album art, as shown by quickly scrolling through and viewing them in Music app, and as confirmed by creating a smart playlist set to “Album Artwork is false”.
In troubleshooting, I find that if on the Mac in Music app I delete the artwork from one of the albums’ complete set of tracks (eg the Beatles’ “Abbey Road”, which has 17 tracks), and then I paste in a replacement image, and then I sync to the iPhone, all tracks for that album now show the artwork image on the iPhone.
I wonder if there could be some corruption in artwork files on some of my tracks, and if so, how would I find which on the Mac? Or is something else more likely?
I do not use any streaming or subscription. I am syncing only via USB cable.
